# Similar to finally Block (JAVA) in Oracle PL/SQL Block

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

As in Java there is finally block which executed in all conditions.

Is there any similar function in Oracle PL/SQL which will be executed whenever procedure completes its execution even a return statement is used?

Comment: Unlike Java, PL/SQL does not support a FINALLY section. You can, however, emulate much of what this section does. Check this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/o19plsql-085133.html and this http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2017/01/emulating-finally-clause-in-plsql.html

Answer (score 6):

There is no equivalent of `FINALLY` but you can simulate it using nested PL/SQL blocks;

```
DECLARE
  -- Your variables.
  return_early BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
  -- Do something

  DECLARE
    -- Local variables in "try" block
  BEGIN 
    -- Equivalent of "try" block
    -- Do something that may raise an exception
    IF some_condition THEN
      return_early := TRUE;
      -- you could also use "GOTO end_try;" rather than surrounding the
      -- following statements in an "ELSE" statement
    ELSE
      -- Do something else that may raise an exception
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN your_exception THEN
      -- Equivalent of "catch" block
  END;
  <<end_try>>
  -- Handle "finally" here, after end of nested block.
  -- Note: you can only see variables declared in this outer block
  --       not variables local to the nested PL/SQL block.
  IF return_early THEN
    RETURN;
  END IF;

  -- Continue and do more stuff.
END;
/
```

Comment: This "finally" part will not run if an unhandled exception is raised in the "try" block.

Comment: @DavidBalažic If you are worried about that then add `WHEN OTHERS THEN ...` to the exception handling block to handle other uncaught exceptions.

Comment: This implementation is similar to, but does not act exactly like `finally` in Java. In Java the `finally` section will be executed if exception not raised, handled successfully, handled with reraising and even if it was not handled at all.

Answer (score 2):

Another thread on Stackoverflow can help out here : [Exception handling in pl/sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252085/exception-handling-in-pl-sql)

Where [Tony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18747/tony-andrews) says :

"You can created nested blocks:"

```
create or replace procedure Trial
    is 
Begin
  begin
    ---Block A--
  EXCEPTION
    when others then
      insert into error_log values('error');
  end;
  begin
    --Block B ----
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions provided in other answers does not implement exact `try-catch-finally` logic. E.g. the `finally` should be executed even if exception is reraised and even if in did not handled at all. In other words, the `finally` block must be called **always**.

The most similar behavior to Java's `finally` is the following. Unfortunately, here we have to wrap `finally` block into a procedure. We have no choice in PL/SQL.

```
declare
begin
  
  declare
    EXPECTED_EXCEPTION_RECOVERABLE exception;
    EXPECTED_EXCEPTION_FATAL exception;
    EXPECTED_EXCEPTION_UNHANDLED exception;
    procedure finally is
    begin
      dbms_output.put_line('FINALLY section executed');
    end;
  begin
  
    dbms_output.put_line('Trying dangerous section...');
    /* uncomment to try different behavior */
    --raise EXPECTED_EXCEPTION_RECOVERABLE;
    --raise EXPECTED_EXCEPTION_FATAL;
    --raise EXPECTED_EXCEPTION_UNHANDLED;
    dbms_output.put_line('Dangerous section is executed successfully');
    FINALLY();

  exception
    when EXPECTED_EXCEPTION_RECOVERABLE then 
      dbms_output.put_line('Recoverable exception handled.');
      FINALLY();
    when EXPECTED_EXCEPTION_FATAL then 
      dbms_output.put_line('Fatal exception handled and will be reraised');
      FINALLY();
      RAISE;
    when OTHERS then
      dbms_output.put_line('Unhandled exception is just reraised after finally section');
      FINALLY();
      RAISE;
  end;
  
end;
/
```

It seems, this solution looks enough readable;

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Exception and then Raise it at the end of your other exceptions, this custom exception must be on an outside block:

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN
     --DO SOME CODE HERE
    EXCEPTION 
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        --HANDLE EXCEPTION
        RAISE CUSTOM_EXCEPTION;
    END;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN CUSTOM_EXCEPTION THEN
      --HANDLE THE FINALLY CODE HERE
END;
```